# Why not all HtmlHelper are working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, html-helper

I am working on Visual Studio on a MVC project. I am trying to use HtmlHelper.
Some are working fine, but other are just not display in the intellisense tool and are not working if I type them. For exmeple BeginForm or DropDownListFor. (but dropdownlist exists...)

**EDIT 1**
It is not working on my computer, but on my collegues, working on the same project/same branch, it is working fine.

[image]

Sorry for the bad screen shot.

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Adding webconfig because asked in comments:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=314E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3664E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF5" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Edit2:**

And more weird : it is working fine in one project (that I newly created) but not on the solution (that I am sharing with others).
[ScreenShots of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk00n.png)

Comment: Can you post your web.config file?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about Razor intellisense issues, what have you tried?

Comment: Everything I ve found. I even asked my collegues around me. And it is not only about intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

From the **[Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx)**

> Use this method in a using block. In that case, the method renders the closing  tag at the end of the using block.

It must be `@using(Html.BeginForm()){}`

You need to wrap it up inside a `using` block inorder to generate a closing `</form>` properly when the using block closes.

Since you are trying out the wrong syntax the intellisense does not show up.

---

**Edit 1:** Since you said most of the syntax dont work.. Try this

Replace the exiting `<host />` tag of yours in the Views -> Web.config with the below line

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: BeginForm does not contain a definition for...etc

Comment: @Stefdelec yes you are right? But why did you bring that point here. I haven't pointed such in my answer.

Comment: @Stefdelec this is from your question `but other are just not display in the intellisense tool and are not working if I type them. For exmeple BeginForm` and My answer is since you are trying the wrong syntax the razor engine cannot show you intellisense as there is nothing for that syntax.

Comment: @Stefdelec which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Not working. I have even tried this:https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-fix-broken-intellisense-in-visual-studio-razor-views/

Comment: @Stefdelec looks serious issue.. Is this issue there right from start or it started recently?

Comment: I think since I m using it (only on my computer).

Comment: hmmm Not sure if something wen wrong while installing your VS. @Stefdelec I have no other clue on what might have gone wrong

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I ll reinstall VS and update SDN.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you need to use a using statement (as for `Html.BeginForm()` since I see that's what you are trying).

For example:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   //Form here
}
```

Same thing goes for `Ajax.BeginForm()`. Also, you'll see that in some cases (like `Html.RenderPartial`) you will have to wrap it inside a razor code block like so: `@{Html.RenderPartial();}`

Here's more info on the subject:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial();} => it doesn't knwo the method...etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems good in webconfig. Do it as below.

1.Run a clean on the solution.

2.Unload the project with the issues

3.Delete the .user file that Visual Studio generated next to the project.

4.Reload the project with the issues

5.Build the solution